# Force change entire background color ignoring div's (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, tags, frontend, background-color

I have multiple sections of my website. I need to change and override each section color to make it black. So I have the `body` tag, and I tried to do it through that on the `css` side of things. I forced the background-color to be black for the entire body, like so.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

but it didn't work. it only changes the background of whatever is not wrapped in its own div or section. Is what I am trying even possible?

Comment: Could you show a bit more of the code. How, for instance, are the sections styled in the first place?

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this by Combining Selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators )

Comment: background-color is not inherited. The default background-color is `transparent`. If you want to change the background-color for all elements within the body use the global selector: `body > * { background-color: black; }`

Comment: @tacoshy this would work fine as long as some element types/classes don't change the background-color (which is why I asked for more code). If the OP is lucky though putting a !important may override them (as long as the other settings don't have an important of course).

Comment: @AHaworth of course, the specificity weight needs to be minded. However you also right that without further details and clarity there can only be general basic answers that might not fully apply to the OP's case.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine HTML elements as layers. You have your main layer (`body`) and you're putting multiple elements on it. If you change the color of the main layer it won't affect the elements on it, because they're one step above on another layer.

You could say each element adds it's own layer to the DOM, so if you want to change something downwards, you have to specify your needs.

## Example

```css
body * {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

This will affect everything under body tag that has no color set.

Another way to achieve this is reseting everything to a certain value then setting the elements you want.

In your case:

```css
* {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

body * {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Since I used the `!important` flag on everything, I must use it when I'm setting the new value, because `!important` overrides specificity.

## Specificity levels:

| Selector | Specificity value |
| --- | --- |
| * { } | 0* |
| li { } | 1 (one element – 0,0,0,1) |
| body#home div#featured p.text | 213 (two id selectors, class selector, 3 HTML selectors – 0,2,1,3) |
| li:first-line { } | 2 (one element, one pseudo-element – 0,0,0,2) |
| ul li { } | 2 (two elements – 0,0,0,2) |
| #footer *:not(nav) li | 23 (one id, two elements – 0,1,0,2)** |
| ul ol+li { } | 3 (three elements – 0,0,0,3) |
| h1 + *[rel=up] { } | 11 (one attribute, one element – 0,0,1,1) |
| ul ol li.first { } | 13 (one class, three elements – 0,0,1,3) |
| li.last.featured { } | 21 (two classes, one element – 0,0,2,1) |
| style=”” | 1000 (one inline styling – 1,0,0,0) |
| div p.big-text { } | 12 (two HTML selectors and a class selector – 0,0,1,2) |
| #author-name { } | 100 (one id selector – 0,1,0,0) |
| body #blog-list .post p { } | 112 (id selector, class selector, 2 HTML selectors – 0,1,1,2) |
| navbar ul.menu li#first a:not(:visited) { } | 133 (id selector, 2 class selectors, 1 pseudo-class, 3 HTML selectors – 0,1,1,2) |

You can read more about the topic [here](https://slicejack.com/quick-guide-to-css-specificity/)

Comment: I know that you copied your answer from the comment section. But you miss a lot of details. You never mentioned the specificty weight which mostlikely will cause a lot of issues. It is the reason I didnt gave it as an answer myself becazuse the topic is way more complex then that.

Comment: Unfortunately for the requirement of this question, it won't affect everything under the body tag if there is other CSS setting the styling of things with more specificity.

Comment: I mean.. yeah, this is why I stated that you have to specify your needs.. I'm sorry that I didn't mention specificity levels, but a simple `!important` can solve the issue. fyi I didn't copy from comments @tacoshy

Comment: maybe `!important` can solve that issue, maybe it doesn't. As @AHaworth correctly commented too, there might be another `!important` used already. One of the many reason why you should not use it in the first place.

Comment: If it's not used anywhere, forcing it on the `body` WILL work.. but again.. you could make everything transparent then reset the `body` to be black as OP wanted